# When i run pip3 freeze or pip3 list there is no output

Tags: python, linux, pip, django-admin, virtualenv

As the title says, when i run `pip3 freeze` or `pip3 list` there is no output on the terminal!

Virtualenv seems also to be broken cause when i was inside of the env it was using the global django-admin.

I did  `sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip` and after that i think it broke.

- OS: Manjaro Linux
- Python3 Version: Python 3.7.4
- Pip3 Version: pip
  19.2.3 from /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out how to cleanly reinstall *pip* (or even Python) from your operating system and really try to avoid anything with `sudo pip` or even `sudo python`. My recommendation is to not even install *pip* at all and use the one preinstalled in the virtual environments (when you do `python3 -m venv .venv`) instead, this is to avoid any conflict with the Python packages installed by your operating system.

Comment: I reinstalled pip and now freeze works, thank you! Why should i not use ```sudo pip``` ? And whats the difference with venv and virtualenv and whats better ?

Comment: And btw ```python3 -m venv .venv``` doesnt work. ```Error: Command '['/home/panos/Dev/Programming/FullStack/ftpm/.venv/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.```

Comment: Your operating system has a package manager. If you use `sudo pip install ...` it will install in the same locations managed by your operating system, and sooner or later conflicts will arise between the Python packages installed by `sudo pip` and the ones installed by your operating system. When you did `sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip` you probably overwrote the version that was previously installed by the package manager of your operating system.

Comment: Ohh yes i have noticed some conflicts with the package manager and i was wondering why this happens xD.

Comment: I prefer using `venv` because it is part of the Python standard library (since Python 3.3) and it just works, never had any issue with it, don't know why one would want to use anything else nowadays. But `virtualenv` must have its advantages as well.

Comment: If `venv` doesn't work, then maybe you did more damage than previously thought. Is there more details than this error message? Try doing a clean reinstall of all the `python` related things that you had installed with the package manager of your operating system.

Comment: I did a python reinstall and it works, thank you :D